# Force Matrix3d or Scale3d for TweenMax?

Tags: html, css, gsap

Im currently trying to perform a scale and shift of two very large (full page) divs with Tweenmax. While my approach works, it is extremely sluggish in Chrome.

I believe this is because Tweenmax is using `Transform: Translate3d(x,y,z) Scale(x,y);` and not `scale3d` or `matrix3d`. Is there anyway to force Tweenmax to use `matrix3d` or `scale3d`?

I have tried using `force3d:true` and that does not seem to work.

Here is my code, the shift and scale separated to make it easier to read for myself...

```
TweenMax.to('#background', 0.1, {scale: 1 + (0.05*dist_perc), delay: 0.01, force3D:true});
TweenMax.to('#foreground', 0.1, {scale: 1 + (0.05*dist_perc), delay: 0.01, force3D:true});

TweenMax.to('#background', 0.1, {x: (0.01*(x_mouse - cx_wind)), y: (0.01*(y_mouse - cy_wind)), delay: 0.01, force3D:true});
TweenMax.to('#foreground', 0.1, {x: (0.015*(x_mouse - cx_wind)), y: (0.015*(y_mouse - cy_wind)), delay: 0.01, force3D:true});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the **z** property (translateZ) with a slight shift to your tweens **z:0.001**

```
TweenMax.to('#background', 0.1, {z:0.001, scale: 1 + (0.05*dist_perc), delay: 0.01, force3D:true});
TweenMax.to('#foreground', 0.1, {z:0.001, scale: 1 + (0.05*dist_perc), delay: 0.01, force3D:true});

TweenMax.to('#background', 0.1, {z:0.001, x: (0.01*(x_mouse - cx_wind)), y: (0.01*(y_mouse - cy_wind)), delay: 0.01, force3D:true});
TweenMax.to('#foreground', 0.1, {z:0.001, x: (0.015*(x_mouse - cx_wind)), y: (0.015*(y_mouse - cy_wind)), delay: 0.01, force3D:true});
```

See if that works. Make sure you are using the **[latest version of GSAP](http://greensock.com/gsap)**. **force3D** now has another option called **force3D:"auto"** .. more info found here in the **[GSAP CSSPlugin](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/Plugins/CSSPlugin/)**.

Also a **[codepen](http://codepen.io/)** or **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)** example will be really helpful so we can see your code in context and edit it live. Just to make sure you don't have any other CSS or JS that could be causing it not to apply matrix3d()